# Matching a column against multiple possible values

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to use `awk` to filter out data from a file. As of now, for a single value I am using the command like the below

```
hadoop fs -text file:///a/b/filename.snappy  awk -F'|'  '$11 == 655' > filter_20180705.txt
```

I want to pass a list of values in comparison section, instead of passing `$11 == 655`, I would like to pass a list like `$11` IN (list). Any thoughts on this will be helpful

Sample-data:

```
karthick,bangalore,software,it,bfsi,spark,hadoop,bigdata,etl,pentaho,655,dev
kumar,bangalore,software,it,bfsi,spark,hadoop,bigdata,etl,pentaho,611,dev
Raj,bangalore,software,it,bfsi,spark,hadoop,bigdata,etl,pentaho,800,dev
John,bangalore,software,it,bfsi,spark,hadoop,bigdata,etl,pentaho,823,dev
```

As of now I am getting the result as

```
karthick,bangalore,software,it,bfsi,spark,hadoop,bigdata,etl,pentaho,655,dev
```

I will need pass a list in the comparison filter. For example, I want to add `611` and `823`. So the expected result would be

```
karthick,bangalore,software,it,bfsi,spark,hadoop,bigdata,etl,pentaho,655,dev
kumar,bangalore,software,it,bfsi,spark,hadoop,bigdata,etl,pentaho,611,dev
John,bangalore,software,it,bfsi,spark,hadoop,bigdata,etl,pentaho,823,dev
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: added the sample data set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a variable in the context of `Awk` (using `-v`) to include alternates for your regex match (separated by `|`) and do your match as below. The `~` is your regex match operator in `Awk` that allows you match `$11` to the string defined (see [How to Use Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Usage.html#Regexp-Usage)).

```
awk -F, -v list="655|611|823" '$11 ~ list' file
```

With the above approach your command translates to match `$11` to any of the entries defined in the variable `list`. To negate your regex match (i.e. opposite of what I want to match), use the negation `!` operator as

```
awk -F, -v list="655|611|823" '$11 !~ list' file
```

To avoid false matches like `1182345` to be part of the match, make the regex more strict by including the start and end patterns

```
awk -F, -v list="655|611|823" 'BEGIN{list="^(" list ")$"} $11 ~ list' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton: Done!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it as the following for efficiency:

```
awk -F, -v list='655,611,823' '
    BEGIN {
        split(list,tmp)
        for (i in tmp) {
            expected[tmp[i]]
        }
    }
    $11 in expected
' file
```

That way you're just doing a hash lookup for each input line rather than a regexp comparison.